# Conditional merge before build in a declarative multi-stage pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a declarative pipeline script, I would like to be able to perform a merge before running the stages, but only when a certain condition is true.

My job is triggered via the Generic Webhook Plugin and I have configured a "merge before build" as "additional behavior" in the Jenkins UI. But now I would like to make this "merge before build" conditional and omit it under certain conditions. I would prefer to do that in the pipeline script. 
All git actions run early before entering a stage, but it seems to be impossible to define a pre action in a stage (like post).

Note that my pipeline runs on different nodes and contains parallel sections. Hence, having one conditional "git merge" stage is not sufficient.